# Web Worker not working after deployment but woking in local

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using z bar processor for barcode reading .I have used web worker to use path of zbar-processor.js.

var worker = new Worker('scripts/directives/zbar-processor.js');

The above code is working fine when running on localhost but gives 404 file not found when i deploy build using grunt clean build.

Comment: Is  deployed page in root of site or same path as in local? Might try adding a leading `/` in url to make it absolute

Comment: No the path changes after deployment it is compressed as regular files. but how cn we give path to make it consistent after deplyment